# Pass items of menu and use map also I want to use default props in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react.js. in my code, I would like to pass these menu items such as dashboard, Customer,.. as props, and I would like to use a map on it. but t i got the same icon `<i className="fas fa-home mr-3">` for all of the menu items. also how I can use the default props for them? could you explain this in two ways ( map and default props)

```
import "./Sidebar.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menuItems: [
        "Dashboard",
        "Customer",
        "Category",
        "Transaction",
        "Pick-up",
        "Stock",
        "Financial",
        "Report",
      ],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <nav id="sidebar">
          <div className="custom-menu">
            <button
              type="button"
              id="sidebarCollapse"
              className="btn btn-primary"
            >
              <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
              <span className="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="p-4">
            <h1>
              <a href="index.html" className="logo">
                Donyaro{" "}
              </a>
            </h1>
            <ul className="list-unstyled components mb-5">
            {this.state.menuItems&&this.state.menuItems.lenght?this.state.menuItems:[]}

              {this.state.menuItems.map((item) => (
                <li className="active">
                  <a href={" "}>
                    <i className="fas fa-home mr-3"></i>
                    {item}
                  </a>
                </li>
               
              ))}
              
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            <a href={" "}>

              <i className="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
            </a>
            <h6>
              <span>Welcome, </span>
              <a href="index.html" className="add-business">
                Add Business
              </a>
            </h6>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 0):

map is a pure function that returns new array based on an array exmple :

```
const array=[1,2,3,4];
const newArr=array.map(el=>el+'a')
 console.log(newArr)=>["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a"];
this is all map doing it iterate over every element of the old array and gives 
back a new array based on what you want to do with the old array.it is very 
useful.
```

I think you do the function right but your problem is with jsx you should wrap your
li element with a div like this

```js
{this.state.menuItems.map((item) => (
             <div>
                <li className="active">
                  <a href={" "}>
                    <i className="fas fa-home mr-3"></i>
                    {item}
                  </a>
                 </li>
                </div>
               
              ))}
```

**

Comment: I used this syntax and I put div, but i would like to set different `<i className="fas fa-home mr-3">` for each of items of menu such as this `<li>
            <a href={" "}><i className="fas fa-user mr-3"></i> Customer</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href={" "}><i className="fas fa-th-large mr-3"></i> Category</a>
          </li>`

Comment: why don't you create a component that recives the props and do the thing that you want it's more efficent .

Comment: I'm new to react and I don't know how I should use props for them

Comment: see the documentation on react website(a link)[https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html]